# Java threads not running concurrently - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore

I'm having a bit of trouble with a multi-threaded application that uses Semaphores I'm attempting to program in Java.

I have a few threads that run in infinite loops to process a set of data in a pipeline.  The 'run' function of each thread looks something like this:

```
public void run()
{
while(true)
{
   try{
    //acquire semaphore, wait if unavailable
    //continue with code
}
   catch(InterruptedException e)
   {}
}
```

My goal is to keep several threads open and run different sets of data through them one at a time, coordinating it with Semaphores.  My problem is that my threads don't seem to be running concurrently.  As soon as I run() a thread with an infinite loop, my entire program hangs, and will not continue.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show the code where all the threads are spawned?

Comment: You probably need to post more information, preferably an [sscce](http://sscce.org). However, first check that you are starting each thread by calling its "start" method, not "run".

Comment: wow, calling my threads with "run" was my problem this whole time, thanks a ton

Comment: @user2968162. like this: ???. Edit your question adding the main method. I think you're invoking `run()` in order to start threads instead of use `start()`.

Comment: What is the Initializing value of Semaphore?

Answer (score 2):

> As soon as I run() a thread with an infinite loop,

```
myThread.start() //correct way

not myThread.run() // this is not the correct way
```